# Importing Python modules in AWS Glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, aws-glue

I'm sending a zip file for an AWS Glue job for the project, and when it runs it, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "redacted.py", line 81, in <module>
'id': id
File "redacted.py", line 53, in update_status
File "redacted.py", line 38, in gzip_compress
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compress'
End of LogType:stdout
```

I've redacted the paths for privacy. The function in question is `gzip.compress` on `line 38` which is a default python library(correct me if I'm wrong). Has anyone else run into this with AWS Glue, and if so, what is a work around for this?

Comment: Do you have file called `gzip.py` in your project directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by using `zlib` library to compress your data with `gzip`